# Count a column according to another column and display the count in different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

This is `table A`

```
Wallet Type       State
------------------------
106                1
106                2
106                1
106                1
106                2
112                1
112                2 
112                2
```

Now i need a table where it counts wallet type according to the state

`Table B` would be like this

```
    State       Distributor(106)  Agent(112)
    ----------------------------------------
    1                  3             1
    2                  2             2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

You can get this using `Aggregate` functions.

**SUM:**

```
SELECT State
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN Wallet_Type = 106 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Distributor_106
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN Wallet_Type = 112 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Distributor_112
FROM Your_Table
WHERE Wallet_Type IN (106, 112)
GROUP BY State
```

**COUNT:**

```
SELECT State
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Wallet_Type = 106 THEN 1 END) Distributor_106
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Wallet_Type = 112 THEN 1 END) Distributor_112
FROM Your_Table
WHERE Wallet_Type IN (106, 112)
GROUP BY State
```

Comment: assuming there won't be a third to 106 and 112.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot table for this case

```
declare @t1 table (wallet_type int, state int)
insert into @t1
values (106,             1),
(106        ,     2       ),
(106        ,     1       ),
(106        ,     1       ),
(106        ,     2       ),
(112        ,     1       ),
(112        ,     2      ),
(112         ,       2    )
--select * from @t1

select *
from 
(
 select state, wallet_type, count(wallet_type) 'count' from @t1 
group by state, wallet_type
) src
pivot
(
  sum(count)
  for wallet_type in ([106], [112])
) piv;
```

Online Demo: http://rextester.com/QBTOQ8569

Answer (score 0):

Try this one... (Dynamic PIVOT)

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(max) = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Quotename(WalletType) 
         FROM   TableName
         FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''); 

DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(max) = ' SELECT *
                                    FROM   TableName
                                           PIVOT ( Count(wallettype) 
                                                 FOR wallettype IN ('+@cols+') ) pvt';

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Output

```
+-------+-----+-----+
| State | 106 | 112 |
+-------+-----+-----+
|     1 |   3 |   1 |
|     2 |   2 |   2 |
+-------+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

These type of problems can also be solved using PIVOT keyword in SQL server.
To know more about PIVOT **[read here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)**.

<kbd>**[see working demo](http://rextester.com/KOH73733)**</kbd>

Your query using PIVOT should be like

```
select 
    [state],
    [Distributor(106)]=[106],
    [Agent(112)]=[112]
from
(
    select 
        [state], 
        [cstate]=state, -- created duplicate as this will be consumed in count operation and will not be available as output column later
        [Wallet Type] 
    from tableA
) src
pivot
(
    count(cstate) for [Wallet Type] in ([106],[112])
    )p
```

Answer (score 0):

First of All, you need to declare a cols Variable that will give you all the distinct Wallet Types that will be used later in the query:

```
 DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(max) =

     Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Convert(nvarchar, WalletType) 
     FROM [IHC].[dbo].[TABLENAMEHERE]
     FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')
```

what it does is, it gets all the distinct comma separated WalletTypes. as XML Path gives you data in XML so we can play with it.

then use PIVOT operator as suggested by some people. here:

```
        select *
from 
(
 select [state], [WalletType], count([WalletType]) as count FROM [IHC].[dbo].[TABLENAMEHERE]
group by [state], [WalletType]
) SourceTable
pivot
(
  sum(count)
  for [WalletType] in (@cols)
) piv;
```

the first part of this query gives you state, WalletType, 'Count of Wallet' Types grouped by state and Wallet Type or say broken w.r.t State and Wallet Type

like this:

state   WalletType  count

---

1       106           4

2       106           2

1       112           1

2       112           2

---

now this 'Count of Wallet' as **count** is used in PIVOT function to get the SUM of COUNT w.r.t the Wallet Types so it sums the count w.r.t WalletType and gives the final result

make sure you use it in a dynamic query.